# How does the dereferencing in this snippet work?

Tags: perl

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this little snippet of code:

```perl
my $ref = \@{$seq->{$label}{$ARGV[4]}};
```

Can I get some help deciphering this?

Answer (score 6):

Lets rewrite it like this

```
my $ref = \@{

    $seq->{ $label }{ $ARGV[4] }

}
```

The outer `my $ref =` is an assignment. I presume that's clear

Then `@{ ... }` *dereferences* the contents of the braces as an array, and `\` then takes a reference to that. The reference cancels out the dereference, so it's *identical* to

```
my $ref = $seq->{ $label }{ $ARGV[4] }
```

except that the dereference will cause the program to die with

> Not an ARRAY reference

if the contents aren't a reference to an array

Now we have

```
$seq->{ $label }{ $ARGV[4] }
```

which uses `$seq` as a reference to a hash of hashes, and uses `$label` as the first-level key and `$ARGV[4]` (the fifth command-line argument) as the second-level key

That statement was written by someone who I will generously call a poor programmer. I doubt if it was intended to check for the hash value being an array reference, and at the very least `$ARGV[4]` should be copied to a named variable to make the meaning clear

Comment: @Tom: That just isn't true, as I tried to explain in my [earlier comment to Matt Jacob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539439/need-help-interpreting-this-perl-code/34540266?noredirect=1#comment56822699_34539579). Try this `perl -E '$r = [ qw/ A B C / ]; $r2 = \@$r; $r2->[2] = q{X}; say qq{$r @$r $r2 @$r2}'` **output** `ARRAY(0x72c530) A B X ARRAY(0x72c530) A B X`. You're probably thinking of `$ref2 = [ @$ref ]` which *does* make a shallow copy

Answer (score 3):

- `$seq` is a hash reference
- `$seq->{$label}` returns the value of the `$label` key in the dereferenced hash
- That value is another hash, from which we get the value of the `$ARGV[4]` key

  - `@ARGV` is the array of command line arguments, `$ARGV[4]` is the element at index 4
- All this returns an array reference, which is dereferenced by `@{...}`
- Adding the backslash in the front turns it back into an array reference

Summary: it's the reference to the array that is the value of the `$ARGV[4]` key in the hash returned by `$seq->{$label}`, and the whole thing could IMHO be written

```
my $ref = $seq->{$label}{$ARGV[4]};
```

See [Borodin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34540266/3266847) for the difference between `\@{$ref}` and `$ref`.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't do the same thing as the original code that was posted, i.e., access a copy of the array vs. the actual referenced array.

Comment: @MattJacob: `\@{$ref} == $ref`. There is no copy

Comment: `\@{$ref}` is a poor way of checking the contents of `$ref`. You should test `ref $ref eq 'ARRAY'` before using it if you have any doubts

Answer (score 1):

```
my $ref = \@{$seq->{$label}{$ARGV[4]}};
```

It's best to work from inside out for order of operation:

1. `$ARGV[4]` : the fifth argument passed in through the command line (e.g., `./perlscript.pl "argument1" "argument2" "argument3" "argument4" "argument5.txt"`)
2. `$seq->{ $label }{ $ARGV[4]}` : this is holding a ref to an array, we know this because when you try to dereference it by wrapping it in `@{ ... }`, you would otherwise receive a warning saying *Not an ARRAY reference*.  Also, in place of variables you could also use bare strings (e.g., `$seq->{ 'some label' }{ 'some other label'}`)
3. `@{ $seq->{ $label }{ $ARGV[4] } }` : this is doing the dereferencing, as mentioned in #3
4. `\@{ $seq->{ $label }{ $ARGV[4] } }` : the slash is making it a reference again, clarifying that an array reference was being held in the hash
5. `my $ref = \@{ $seq->{ $label }{ $ARGV[4] } };` : your standard variable assignment

---

We haven't seen much other code, so it's tough to say how much this may need updated.  Usually you would want to sanitize your inputs, to make sure no bad or extremely large data is being passed in.  Additionally, you would want to make it more meaningful.  `$seq` could be sequence or anything really, `$label` is not too identifiable, and using any `$ARGV` as you have done, generally means something else is not being done elsewhere.